# How do you do clickthrough tracking via the FB Share Dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to Facebook's documentation for the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), you can use Javascript to trigger open a share dialog so that the user can share whatever URL you pass in:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs?myTrackingParam=topShareButton',
}, function(response){});
```

However, if you want to do any referral tracking by appending a query string to the `href` property gets stripped, since the FB uses the `og:url` meta tag when it crawls the URL. I use the query params to track which share buttons are causing the most traffic. So my question: how can you do clickthrough tracking via the FB Share Dialog? Is there a way to set some query string value in the URL when sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation and piecing together separate FB docs, you can indeed set whatever value that gets passed back in the [`fb_ref` query param](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#params). However, this requires us to turn the share into an Open Graph call.

So instead of using the `share` method, we could use the [`share_open_graph`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) method. Thus, we can set the `action_properties`, which would include the `ref` property:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.shares',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs',
      ref: 'topShareButton'
  })
}, function(response){});
```

Thus, the link that is shown on the Newsfeed/Timeline will be `https://developers.facebook.com/docs?fb_ref=topShareButton`. And now you can do whatever tracking your heart desires!

Comment: So to clarify - `ref` doesn't work on the regular share dialog, but it does on the open graph share dialog? (I can see what you're doing using one for the other though)

Comment: @ChrisHoughton Yes, the `ref` param only works with OG share dialog (because it's dependent on the `action_properties` which is only accepted for OG actions). The one thing thing I still need to confirm is whether or not this OG share still counts as a "Share" Action Type in the App Insights.